How to organize overlapping meetings in Outlook 365
When using the calendar in Outlook (Office 365), I have multiple overlapping meetings. When this happens, Outlook will put meetings into different columns. How can I move these meetings to a desired column? For example, I have a standing meeting that goes for most of the day, and then several other meetings overlapping it. Outlook is placing the huge standing meeting in the center column, with other meetings to either side of it.
I would like to have the large standing meeting off to one side or the other, with other meetings in columns next to each other.
How can I change the right-to-left order in which Outlook displays overlapping meetings?

In Outlook, the position of meetings in the calendar view is determined automatically and cannot be manually adjusted to a specific column. The arrangement is typically based on the duration of the meetings, with longer meetings often displayed in the center. Unfortunately, there isn’t a built-in feature that allows you to change the right-to-left order of overlapping meetings directly.
However, there are a couple of workarounds you might consider:
Edit the Subject: If Outlook is arranging the meetings alphabetically, you could edit the subject of the meetings to control their order.
Custom Views: You can create a custom view to hide certain meetings, such as cancelled ones, which might help in organizing the view to your preference.
Also, here's a similar thread with suggestions for managing overlapping meetings. Please refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1189870/outlook-calendar

Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.
